# Issue in recursive loop : JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**About the below code**

I am trying to delete the roles and it's child roles recursively in Js. In the below Html: data-id="2" is RoleID and data-parentid="1" is Parent Role.

**Problem**

When debugger comes at last row, it does not go back to its parent row which is already traversed in the loop.

Am I missing anything?

**Html Part**

```
<table id="RoleList" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>         
        <tr data-id="15">
            <td>under first</td>
            <td>first</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="16" data-parentid="15">
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>under first</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="17" data-parentid="16">
            <td>under second</td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS Part**

```
function RemovedDeletedRoles(RoleID) {
    var Roles = $("#RoleList").find("tr[data-parentID='" + RoleID + "']");
    $.each(Roles, function(index, row) {
        var ID = $(row).attr("data-id");
        var childRoles = $("#RoleList").find("tr[data-parentID='" + ID + "']");
        if(childRoles.length === 0) {
            $(row).remove();
        }
        else {
            RemovedDeletedRoles($(row).attr("data-id"));
        }
    });
}
```

**DOM Ready Event**

```
$(document).on("click", ".DeleteRole", function() {
    var deleteButton = $(this);
    var roleID = $(deleteButton).parent().parent().attr("data-id");
    RemovedDeletedRoles(roleID);
    $(deleteButton).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: What is the code trying to do? How should the final HTML look? it should just remove the whole table?

Comment: Yes, it should finally remove whole table. Kindly let me know if you need more info. Thank you very much for checking the problem in details

Comment: So I click a delete button with ID 16, what should happen?

Comment: if you click `<tr data-id="15">`, it should delete all table. if you delete `<tr data-id="16">`, it should delete `<tr data-id="16"` and also `<tr data-id="17"` because that is child of 16

Comment: So - `<tr>` is a table row. You want to delete all entries with an id greater? and 17 is not a child of 16, it's techically a child of `tbody`

Comment: Not entirely true. Let's say we pick data-id = 15. It will check those tr where data-parent = 15. As per the above table there is tr with data-id = 16 where parent = 15. Now in the recursion, we will check those where tr where parent = 16 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code that work fine:

```
<table id="RoleList" class="table table-bordered">
    <tbody>         
        <tr data-id="15">
            <td>under first</td>
            <td>first</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="16" data-parentid="15">
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>under first</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-id="17" data-parentid="16">
            <td>under second</td>
            <td>Second</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>
                <button class="DeleteRole btn btn-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

//direction 0:remove children, 1:remove parents
function RemoveRoles(roleId, direction) {
        direction=direction || 0; //remove by defautl remove children
        //alert("RoleId:"+roleId+" - direction->"+(direction==0?"children":"parents"));
        var $tr=$("#RoleList").find("tr[data-id='" + roleId + "']");
    var parentId=$tr.data("parentid");  
    var itemsToRemove = [];
    if(direction==0){
        itemsToRemove=$("#RoleList").find("tr[data-parentid='" + roleId + "']");
    }else{   
        itemsToRemove=$("#RoleList").find("tr[data-id='" + parentId + "']");
    }
    //alert(itemsToRemove.length);
    $tr.remove();
    $.each(itemsToRemove, function(index, item) {    
        var id = $(item).data("id");            
        RemoveRoles(id, direction);        
    });
}

$(document).on("click", ".DeleteRole", function() {
    var deleteButton = $(this);
    var roleID = $(deleteButton).parent().parent().attr("data-id");
    RemoveRoles(roleID, 1);
    $(deleteButton).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Try it